# Getting value from php form

Tags: php, database

I am trying to insert into a database posted form values, retrieved from an html form that was generated via php. However it is not inserting the values, however I do see the values when I print the posted variables. Here is the code.

This is the form written in php that outputs html

```
<?php 
$find = mysql_query("SELECT file_name FROM chemlab_files WHERE student_id = '$student_id'") or die  ("Could not search!");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($find)){
    $file_name = $row['file_name'];
    $_SESSION['file_name'] = $file_name;
    echo "<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='file_name[]' value='{$file_name}'>$file_name</label><br><input type='text' name='description[]' value='' placeholder='description'>";
    }
?>
```

This is the form handler

```
//description
            if(isset($_POST['description'])){
            foreach($_POST['description'] as $description){ 
                $file_name_description = mysql_real_escape_string($description);
            //print_r($file_name_description);
              }
             }



            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chemlab_files WHERE student_id='$student_id'") or die (mysql_error());              

           //if the student_id does exist, proceed
                if($result==1){
                    //insert into chemlab_files update description
                    $insert_file_name_description = mysql_query("UPDATE chemlab_files SET description='$file_name_description'  WHERE file_name='$file_name'");                     
                }else{
                    echo 'something went wrong during sharing!';
                    exit();
```

I can print the variable $file_name_description but cannot insert into the database.

To be more clear the form has multiple fields, for ever file_name (checkbox with value ="$file_name") has a description field. When I do print_r for $file_name and $description I get the values for all the fields. However when I go to insert the description into the database nothing happens.

Comment: You don't seem to be defining `$file_name` anywhere

Comment: have you tried placing `` around the column headers?

Comment: What is the value of `$file_name`? That's probably you're problem.

Comment: In addition to the above, you seem to be checking for the existence of a student, but inserting contingent on a file name.  You should probably define and check for the file name.  Also you should look into using mysqli or pdo for database interactions.

Comment: The $file_name was defined earlier in my script. I managed to get the rest of the script working this is the only part that is not inserting is the description. Each file_name has a description field, the file_name already exist but the description does not exist yet and would like insert into the database.

Comment: that or the problem is in my foreach loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

you need this.

Comment: Hmm...how do I define the value for each description when the form is like `<?php

echo "<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='file_name[]' value='{$file_name}'>$file_name</label><br><input type='text' name='description[]' value='' placeholder='description'>";

?>`

Comment: define hmz. What do you mean ? Do u wanna change the value of above text?

Comment: when I put `value=''` it will only insert the value in the last field. I should have value for every description but since the form is being generated by php I am confused about what to change the value too....(i am a beginner at this)

Comment: can you paste your full code? where is your loop i cannot see it

Comment: I posted it up on the main question

Comment: thanks! It still doesn't work because their is no $description in the form, it would be what ever the user inputs. I figure it must be something wrong with the query because I can see the values when I print_r but it won't insert.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a new database record, shouldn't your sql be an INSERT statement like

```
INSTERT INTO chemlab_files SET (description, name) VALUES ('$file_name_description','$file_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems:

1. I do not understand why the text input in your HTML is an array (description[])
2. I don't see why you iterate it at the beginning, and you always set the `$file_name_description` to the last value. Are you trying to append all posted `description` inputs to the `$file_name_description` variable? If yes, then you should write `.=` instead of `=`